# An extension method for Session variables

Tags: c#

I created the following extension method:

```
    public static bool HasHostAndUrl(this HttpSessionStateBase session)
    {
        return session["CurrentUrl"] != null && session["CurrentHost"] != null;
    }
```

I also have the following that appears in my code. Is it possible I could make this into an extension method also:

```
string.Format("http://{0}{1}",
   Session["CurrentHost"],
   new Uri((string)Session["CurrentUrl"]).PathAndQuery)
```

Comment: How is this different from `Request.Url`?

Comment: Request URL reports the wrong port when using windows azure emulator.

Comment: Still confused. You obviously know how to declare extension methods and have ready-to-go body for it... Whats the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
public static string FormatHostAndUrl(this HttpSessionStateBase session)
{
    return string.Format("http://{0}{1}",session["CurrentHost"],new Uri((string)Session["currentUrl"]).PathAndQuery);
}
```